# Highlight gridview row based on datatable values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I need to highlight gridview rows based on values from datatable.
I have highlighted values like if any particular cell values has met some conditions then I can highlight using this code.

```
if(int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,"Risk").ToString()) > 100)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA");
    }
```

Now my questions is, in my rowdatabound event I want to check values in datatable and I need to highlight values in the gridview.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        { 
            DataTable dt = DataRepository.highlightRow();
            string[] strInactive = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("product_id")).ToArray();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvProducts.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gvProducts.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (gvProducts.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.Contains("how to pass array values"))
                    {
                        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For ex:
Here the datatable will return only one column values like this,10, 20, 20. Then I need to highlight rows of these values in the gridview.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What doesn't work?

Comment: @j.f. - I am struggling to check datatable values in gridview. I have highlighted rows like which has static values and greater than or lesser than. But this looks bit tricky to me.

Comment: firstly your code will waste too much time un-necessarily. because 1. `DataTable dt = DataRepository.highlightRow();` is called on each row. 2. foreach and for loop runs on each row.

Comment: can you edit your question and say what the contents of your datatable are? also exactly what do you wanna compare with?

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to check `e.Row.DataItem` for values that meet your criteria

You can do something like this in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
  DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem;

  if( drv("Risk") == <some condition> ) {
    e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black // :)
  }
}
```

Comment: What I need to give in some condition? How can I can check for datatable values in gridview.

Comment: Is the datatable  the datasource for the gridview?

Comment: No the datatable is not the datasource for the gridview. It's a seperate one and I am doing a join with a datatable of the gridview source. I need to highlight the matched rows.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
    private const System.Drawing.Color HIGHLIGHT = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    private const System.Drawing.Color NORMAL = System.Drawing.Color.White;

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataTable dt = DataRepository.highlightRow();
            string[] strInactive = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<string>("product_id")).ToArray();
            foreach (var value in strInactive)
            {
              e.Row.BackColor = (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == value) ? HIGHLIGHT : NORMAL;
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know what is in your DataTable, so I don't know what you want to test for.

Comment: OK, thanks for the prompt answer. Assume my datatable returns three values like G-01, G-02, G-03. Now I need to check this value in gridview first row and highlight them. Datatable values are dynamic and they will keep changing.

Comment: I edited the code to include a `foreach` loop using the table results. Would that get you where you want to be?

Comment: The logic looks perfect to me, but the rows are not getting highlighted.

Comment: That's getting into the part of ASP.NET that I'm not sure of. Do you have any CSS or Styles that might be going on? If so, you might have to look to JavaScript to update your HTML.

Comment: when I debugged it taking values perfectly and I'm not having any css or styles on that aspx.

Comment: Try substituting `e.Row.BackColor` with `gvProducts.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex].BackColor`. I don't know, but maybe.